# Login Page With React On Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to create authentication on react, but now I am currently stuck as my try and catch block is not working. When I click the signup button, I am not getting any error nor any response from the site. No user is uploaded to the Firebase database.
The Code is Given Below.

```
import React,{useRef,useState} from 'react'
import {Form,Button,Card,Alert} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {useAuth} from '../Context/AuthContext'

function Signup() {
    const emailRef=useRef()
    const passwordRef=useRef()
    const passwordConfirmRef=useRef( )
    const {signup} =useAuth();
    const [error,setError]=useState();
    const [loading,setLoading]=useState(false); 

   async function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        if(passwordRef.current.value!==passwordConfirmRef.current.value){
            return setError("Passwords Do Not Match")
        }
        try{
            setError("");
            setLoading(true);
           await signup(emailRef.current.value,passwordRef.current.value)
        }
        catch {setError("Failed To Create An Account")}
        setLoading(false);
    }
}
 
export default Signup
```

Answer (score 0):

Try catch block looks like this:

```js
try {
   ...
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}
```

Are you sure you paste correct code ? `Signup()` don't have closing brackets. I don't see in your code that you're importing `signup()` function. And your main function is named `Signup()` this is not a good practice. A good name for your function can be `onSignUp()` instead of `Signup()`.

Comment: I am not able to share my full code here. Is there any way to share it??

Comment: @Milan You can edit your question. I edited your question, you can approve. This is how it works.

Comment: @Milan Or I got to high rank, and you don't need to approve my edits. <2k people who edit questions need approve.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Letsbuilditnow/d0d1a4ddda70c07213ff4da31e1577ff

Answer (score 0):

The Submit Button Type Was Not Mentioned In The Above Code. So It Was Not Submitting And Hence No Error Were Shown In The Console.
So Just Add `type='submit'` To The Submit Button And The Code Will Work Properly.